# Forwarding content URI permission from Activity to a bound Service in another app

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-contentprovider

I am implementing a system where I take a picture, show it to the user, and upload it. For reasons beyond the scope of this question, I have three apps involved: the system's camera app, my app that shows the UI, and a third app that handles the upload. I own all three apps and can deploy code changes to each.

The problem is that the upload Service (in the third app) doesn't always have access to the content URI and sometimes fails with a `SecurityException: Permission Denial`.

This is what I do:

1. The UI app requests a picture be taken by the Camera app
2. The Camera app starts, takes a picture, and returns the result back to the UI app with a URI and the `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` flag in the `Intent`
3. The UI app receives the result, has permission to access the URI, loads/displays the picture taken in an `ImageView`
4. Upon user click, my app binds to the Service in the third app and attempts to grant URI permission/access to the service by setting the URI in the `data` property of the `Intent` passed into `bindService` and setting the `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`
5. My `Activity` then finishes itself
6. The Service app service is started and bound to, it receives the URI to upload and, sometimes, fails with a `SecurityException`

---

My questions are:

1. Is it even possible to forward URI permission access from a component in one app (my Activity) to another component in another app (the upload Service)?
2. Same question, but what if the component in the other app is a bound service and not a started service, do I use the `Intent` passed into the `bindService` call to do this? What if the service is already running from before?
3. Since `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` is designed to automatically revoke permissions once the life-cycle ends, does that mean that the access granted from the `Activity` to the bound `Service` is revoked once the `Activity` is finished even though the lifespan of a `Service` should be longer by design?

Comment: `2. The Camera app starts, takes a picture, and returns the result back to the UI app with a URI and the FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION flag in the Intent` No. A normal camera app will not deliver an uri in onActivityResult. And no uri no flag.

Comment: `1. The UI app requests a picture be taken by the Camera app`. Yes, but you forgot to tell that the intent to start the camera app has an extra with the uri for a file where the camera app can write the picture to. Possible also because it is comes with a flag grant write uti permission.

Comment: `3. The UI app receives the result, has permission to access the URI, loads/displays the picture taken in an ImageView`. The only thing that is received in onActivityResult is an ok code. And as there was an uri  (see 1.) it can be used.

Comment: Your app constructs an uri -using a FileProvider- which is used by the Camera app to write an image to. The same uri can be used by an upload app. This app needs only read permission granted. If this app uses a service or not is beyond your control, hence irrelevant. Unless you programmed that app too.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write these comments, @blackapps - a couple of points:
a. We own all 3 apps
b. The camera app is indeed non-standard, it creates the file and its URI, it also supports video, for which even standard camera apps do this so that point is moot (I have a similar flow where I also want to record and upload a video)

Comment: "Is it even possible to forward URI permission access from a component in one app (my Activity) to another component in another app (the upload Service)?" -- it seems to work most of the time for you, so, presumably, it works, just not reliably. My guess is the problem is "My Activity then finishes itself", with a corresponding timing issue related to when the service actually gets the permission. I have never tried passing `Uri` permissions to bound services. If you are getting the failure on your development machine, try postponing the `finish()` call, and see if that helps.

Comment: `We own all 3 apps ` If you ever post again then please tell right away.

Comment: `If you ever post again then please tell right away.`

I did, but maybe it was drowned by the rest of the text in the original question. Grep for "I own all three apps and can deploy code changes to each." on this page ;)